# Javascript API for Chrome inspect element

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

In Chrome's inspect element, we can see box-model of any element :

[image]

Is there any api from Chrome using which I can display above box-model within a page itself ?

Answer (score 0):

Chrome does not expose the inspector element directly, but you can find the code that generates the box: https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/devtools/front_end/MetricsSidebarPane.js&l=137

(this manually generates the required elements)

The style used in that function comes from `window.getComputedStyle`

Comment: I checked it, the parameter for the function is 'style' but I am not able to figure out what it could be? That page also does not mention anything about it. It would be great if you can give a small example!

Comment: @avi it comes from         `WebInspector.cssModel.getComputedStyleAsync(node.id, callback.bind(this));` which appears to reference the native function https://code.google.com/p/chromium/codesearch#chromium/src/third_party/WebKit/Source/core/inspector/InspectorCSSAgent.cpp&l=1136&q=getcomputedstyleforNode&type=cs&sq=package:chromium (which also appears in the pipeline to compute window.getComputedStyle), so I assume that you can pass the object from that function